# Errors creating spatial raster bricks using the R package terra function rasterize only on linux

Tags: r, terra

the R terra package has the function 'rasterize' which has the option 'by' to split data by a column. This makes creating a layered raster (raster brick) from spatial points really quick and easy. However, when I pass it to a linux machine with the same packages installed I get a few errors that aren't particularly self explanatory. Example below using some aq data from the saqgetr package.

```
library(saqgetr)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

## import some aq sites
s <- fread('http://aq-data.ricardo-aea.com/R_data/saqgetr/helper_tables/sites_table.csv.gz')[1:50,] %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = 4326)

##create raster for domain
r <- rast(s, res=1, vals = 1)

## get observations for sites
s_dat <- get_saq_observations(site = s$site, start = 2023) %>% 
  filter(variable == "pm10" & date < "2023-01-01 12:00") %>% ## pick out pm10 and first 11 hours
  mutate(date = as.character(date)) %>% ## make date a character to enable layers to be easily defined
  left_join(s, by = "site") %>% ## join with geometry
  select(date, value, geometry) ## pick out columns needed

## define geometry column
st_geometry(s_dat) <- s_dat$geometry

## create terra vector
sv <- terra::vect(s_dat)
  
## create raster brick for each hour
b <- terra::rasterize(sv, r, field = "value", fun = 'mean', by = "date")

## see what it looks like
plot(b)
```

If I run this on Windows I get this output which is exactly what I expect [image]

But if I give to a linux machine running 4.1.2 first I get an error creating a raster from the sf points:

```
##create raster for domain
r <- rast(s, res=1, vals = 1)

*Error in methods::as(x, "SpatRaster") : 
  no method or default for coercing "sf" to "SpatRaster"*
```

If I supply a pre-generated raster and it gets to the rasterize I get this:

```
## create raster brick for each hour
b <- terra::rasterize(sv, r, field = "value", fun = 'mean', by = "date")

*Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'list(g)' is not a function, character or symbol*
```

Comment: Does the output of `sessionInfo()` suggest a significant version difference between {terra} (and/or other relevant spatial packages) between your Win and Linux machines? If so, you might give it a try adapting your Linux package versions to the working Win setup.

Comment: Linux R version is 4.1.2 and windows is 4.3.0. I suppose that could be the issue. Not so straight forward to update the Linux version as it on a third party server.

Comment: The R version might be less of a hindrance than version differences of *packages*, especially {terra} whose version on your Linux seems to be unable to handle `sf` objects (hence the error `no method or default for coercing "sf" to "SpatRaster"`).

Comment: As hinted at this was solved by updated to the latest version of terra.